# Javascript Countdown Timer does not reset

Tags: javascript, timer, reset

I am writing a quiz style application where each question has a countdown timer running. At the end of the countdown the application moves on to the next question. However, on answering the question the timer is supposed to reset. It does not do this and instead creates a new timer, so once the first timer reaches zero it moves on to the next question, which it shouldn't do. I am using the countdown timer from http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/ and my code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.countdown = '';

    function resetTimer()
    {
        window.countdown = new Countdown({ 
            time: 30,
            inline: true,
            rangeHi  : "minute",
            target: "timer",
            width: 50,
            height: 30,
            onComplete : skipQuestion
         });
    }
</script>
```

Everytime a question is answered (or when the timer runs out and skipQuestion() is called), I call the function resetTimer(). My javasscript is not that great, so instead of trying to reach the developer of the countdown timer, I was hoping that the vast collection of knowledgeable people on here might give me an indication of how to get this working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Simply calling window.countdown.init() resets the timer.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
window.clearInterval(window.countdown);
```

to stop the running timer. Your code creates a new time anytime you call resetTimer(), so your function should be called createTimer();

Comment: Thank you for you input, unfortunately clearInterval did not work. I do not think that the countdown timer uses SetInterval.

Comment: What I have now done is I have added a line to the function resetTimer() just before I call new Countdown. I have tried window.clearInterval(window.countdown), clearInterval(window.countdown), window.clearTimeout(window.countdown) and clearTimeout(window.countdown). None of these have worked and the original timer still kept going. If I am not understanding your answer correctly, could you please elaborate? Please remember my javascript is not too great.